# knockout.js - when do computed items recalculate dependencies?

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

Suppose you have the following js:

```
  var vm = {
    objects: ko.observable([]),
    objectCount: ko.computed(function(){
      return vm && vm.objects().length;
    }),

    add: function() {
      var current = vm.objects();
      current.push({});      
      console.log('current is', current);
      vm.objects(current);
      console.log("should recalculate here", vm.objectCount());
    }
  };
```

And the following html:

```
  <ul data-bind="foreach: objects">
    <li>
      Object: <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button data-bind="click: add">Add Object</button>
  <p>
    Total number of objects:
    <span data-bind="text: objectCount"></span>
  </p>
```

It is my understanding [from reading the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#how_dependency_tracking_works) that because after I add an object I call objectCount(), that it should recalculate its dependencies. Instead it seems to never even execute the function, running it only once!

[JSBin demonstrating a simplified version of my issue.](http://jsbin.com/welcome/58741/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a scoping issue. If you refactor your script code to look like this:

```
$(function(){
  var vm = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.objects = ko.observable([]);
    self.objectCount = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.objects().length;
    });

    self.add = function() {
      var current = self.objects();
      current.push({});      
      console.log('current is', current);
      self.objects(current);
      console.log("should recalculate here", self.objectCount());
    };
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new vm());
});
```

Then the correct variables are scoped and Knockout correctly calculates the dependencies. As stated by [guigouz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13767716/11702), when `ko.computed` is initially called, `vm` is undefined, so it cannot setup any change handlers.

Here is [the updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/58745/edit)

Answer (score 4):

Defining your computed after defining your viewModel works - http://jsbin.com/welcome/58760/ - it happens because of the way computed observables work (from ko docs).

1. Whenever you declare a computed observable, KO immediately invokes
   its evaluator function to get its initial value.
2. While your evaluator function is running, KO keeps a log of any
   observables (or computed observables) that your evaluator reads the
   value of.
3. When your evaluator is finished, KO sets up subscriptions to each of
   the observables (or computed observables) that you’ve touched. The
   subscription callback is set to cause your evaluator to run again,
   looping the whole process back to step 1 (disposing of any old
   subscriptions that no longer apply).
4. KO notifies any subscribers about the new value of your computed
   observable.

When instantiating the observable inside the vm object, the other properties do not exist yet.

Comment: Right, but point 3 implies that it would re-calculate, would it not?  Though on a more careful reading it implies that the value is memoized and only updated when a subscriber updates (explaining my issue). I do want to point out though that removing checkmarks in your example does not work though - since these are also observable I'm not sure why that is the case.

Comment: But when the evaluator finished, there were no observables on your vm object (they didn't exist yet because the var statement was not finished). 
checked() wasn't working because you were using the value: binding instead of checked: on the checkbox, here's the updated fiddle - http://jsbin.com/welcome/58799/ - i also changed objects to an observableArray, this way ko only renders the new elements when you push them, instead of re-rendering the whole array.
I also recommend defining your viewmodels as functions and instantiating them as Josh proposed, but that didn't explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the `deferEvaluation` option for `ko.computed`. This will tell Knockout to wait to evaluate the computed observable until it's first used. By that time, `vm` will be defined.

```
objectCount: ko.computed(function(){
  return vm && vm.objects().length;
}, null, { deferEvaluation: true }),
```

Comment: Oh, good tip, didn't know about that one. As much as I like the tutorial-style, I really ''do'' wish they also had some api docs.

Comment: There is a short reference section for `ko.computed`: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#computed_observable_reference